# Wrong rendering of js object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have some structure that I want to render to my JADE page, so I decided to make JSON-like object to render some kind of data (variables, text, js objects), this JSON object looks like :

```
var dataSet1 = {
meta: {
    "name": "Some text",
    "minimum": mini_2,
    "maximum": maxi_2,
    "currentValue": last_data_2
},
data: {
    "values": dataTwo,
    "corridor": {
        "x1": xc,
        "x2": yc2,
        "yw": yw2
    }
}
};
```

My render line:

```
res.render('index', {
data_to_draw: dataSet1
});
```

Then I`m using this rendered data on my JADE:

```
    displayGraphExampleOne("#graph",
                        !{data_to_draw.data.values},
                        !{data_to_draw.meta.currentValue},
                        !{data_to_draw.meta.minimum},
                        !{data_to_draw.meta.maximum},
                        !{data_to_draw.meta.name},
                        !{data_to_draw.data.corridor.x1},
                        !{data_to_draw.data.corridor.x2},
                        !{data_to_draw.data.corridor.yw2});
```

Cannot read property 'values' of undefined Im getting such type of error.
Im new with JS , so Im trying to decide what i`m doing wrong. If I will pass data not in js object - it works well, but i need such type of passing data. thanx

Comment: Other than that you have quoted some (but not all) of the property names (which is valid JS), your object is just an object, not a JSON object. I mention this because you have code fragments above, so if you are operating on `dataSet1` to do JSON stuff with it, you might not end up with the object you want to be getting. A `console.log(dataSet1)` right before your render command will probably give you a hint (or in place of `render()` if you are crashing out and losing console output). You can also `console.log(require('util').inspect(dataSet1, {depth: null}))` to get a fully-expanded object.

Answer (score 0):

It was just misunderstanding in what I was rendering, I was rendering an array, so I should use this construction for correct call and pass:

```
function d3_drawer(input_array, element_id) {
            for (var i=0; i < input_array.length; i++) {
                displayGraphExampleOne(element_id,
                input_array[i].data.values,
                input_array[i].meta.currentValue,
                input_array[i].meta.name,
                input_array[i].data.corridor.rmin,
                input_array[i].data.corridor.rmax,
                input_array[i].data.corridor.nmin,
                input_array[i].data.corridor.nmax);
            }
        }
```